# Themes for jQTouch

Tags: themes, jqtouch

I've been using jQTouch to make an iphone-like website. But, I don't want it to look like a native iPhone app (Since people will be using it on other phones), but I don't really like the included JQT theme. Anyone know any other themes? I've searched long and hard, but can't find any. If worst comes to worse, I guess I could always make my own, but I'm not too good at graphics. Just wondering if anybody knows about any others, including those in demos?

Thanks in advance!

-Leticia Meyer

Answer (score 9):

I've created one, [available for download here](http://www.theartspot.be/blog/2010/12/08/jqtouch-theme/)

It's easily customizable, has Retina support and uses lots of CSS3 and a minimum amount of images.

**2018-08-02**: link to [download from webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20120120112336/http://www.theartspot.be/upload/jqtouch_theme_artspot.zip)

Comment: Sweet @senne! That theme looks amazing!!

Comment: Old post I know.  sadly the link is no longer working.  Any other options?

Comment: You can find documentation for theming jQTouch right here: https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/Theming. It's fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

as per my point of view you don't need to have graphics knowledge, coz in jqtouch you can use css3 and using that you can develop a kick ass theme.